# How to clone a content type?

Tags: 7

I want to clone a node type and add a few fields in it. I think the simplest will be to duplicate it and start working on it.

It seems there is no official way to clone a content type in Drupal 7. Features may allow it but there is no written procedure as to how it could be done.

I've even tried [Bundle Copy](https://www.drupal.org/project/bundle_copy) module.

What'll be best way to clone any content type in Drupal 7?

Comment: I only just noticed you tried bundle copy...I use that all the time, what didn't work?

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11645/how-to-copy-content-type-in-drupal-7

Comment: @NikhilM Adding fields makes this a similar question, but not a dup of 11645.

Answer (score 12):

The easiest way is to use the [Bundle copy](http://drupal.org/project/bundle_copy) module, but if you can't get that to work I'd recommend the [Configuration Management](http://drupal.org/project/configuration) module.

> The configuration management module enables the ability to keep track of specific configurations on a Drupal site, provides the ability to move these configurations between different environments (local, dev, qa, prod), and also move configurations between completely different sites (migrate configurations) without the use of modules with all configuration being owned by the site.

It's basically features with the stuff you don't need. Its sole purpose is to move configuration from one site to another.

Comment: How to use Bundle copy? I've exported Article type - now what do I do to change it's name before importing the same code?

Comment: Just run a string replace...replace 'old_content_type' with 'new_content_type', I've never had a problem using that method before

Comment: Thanks ... can I replace "article" for cloning Article content type?

Comment: Yes, but make sure your string replace is case sensitive and includes the apostrophes (it's not an exact science). So the PHP code would look like `str_replace("'article'", "'new_type'", $export_code);`

Comment: You mean only machine name needs to replaced?

Comment: In my experience yes. It's worth having a look through the export code to make sure though

Comment: I'm trying to export "Article" type and import it using another name. I don't know what to do with this code : `'bundles' => array(
        'node' => array(
          0 => 'page',
          1 => 'article',
          2 => 'forum',
          3 => 'webform',
          4 => 'book',
          5 => 'article_with_address',
        ),
      ),`  so should I simply replace 'article' here? Will it affect anything?

Comment: @AgA, I just tried this technique and I added my new content type to the 'bundles' array rather than replacing the one I was cloning.  I don't know what replacing it would do.

Comment: +1 upvote on your answer here @Clive - we've just used Bundle Copy here - it provides a menu option 'clone' under 'Structure' in the Drupal admin/config menus to clone the content type. Exactly what we hoped for when considering this module. It seems to work fine.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using the [Field Tools Module](http://drupal.org/project/field_tools) for D7; it does exactly what you need.

Comment: Does this help to migrate multifields, unsure how to use this

Answer (score 3):

[Feature](http://drupal.org/project/features) module is best option yet.
Here's what you need to do:

- Export the content type that you want to clone as a Feature.
- Re-name the content type (i.e., change the "machine name") in your Drupal
  site
- Upload and enable your Feature

[This page](http://drupal.org/node/1011620) may have your answer for "official way to clone a content type in Drupal 7".

Comment: Can't agree with that sorry. Bundle copy is much easier to use (and more lightweight) than features. Ditto Configuration

Comment: Can you please tell me which fields to change exactly in the exported module and link about this "official" information?

Comment: +1 @Clive - we've just used Bundle Copy here - it provides a menu option 'clone' under 'Structure' in the Drupal admin/config menus to clone the content type. Exactly what we hoped for when considering this module. It seems to work fine.

Comment: @monymirza this would involve editing machine generated code by hand to search/replace/rename the feature-generated content type code. Unless one knows the Feature module code well as to how it generates this code, there may be unknowns/assumptions made about hand coding this way and unlucky outcomes. Use the *dev version* (at time of writing, currently 7.x-2.x-dev) of Bundle Copy (corrected my original comment made on Oct 1 '14 at 10:29 to mention functionality currently in dev version) as this provides a 'clone' menu option in 'structure' menu, out of the box, it was made for this task.

Answer (score 3):

I've created Content Type Clone, available as a sandbox project here:

https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/davidfiaty/2745827

It allows you to clone a content type in one click without having to look at PHP code or perform complex manipulations.

It's still a sandbox project at the moment but it will soon be available as an official Drupal module. Check it out!

Edit 1:
The official release of Content Type Clone for Drupal 7 is here!
https://www.drupal.org/project/content_type_clone
Drupal 8 version coming soon.

Edit 2:
The official release of Content Type Clone for Drupal 8 is available on the same page.