# Is there any way to clone a content type

Tags: nodes

My site has a lot of different content types, they all have the same fields, the only difference is the name of the content type. Is there any way to clone those content types other than create them one by one. Thanks.

Comment: a simple google search could have helped you.
here you go   
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/57589/how-to-clone-a-content-type

Comment: also check this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11645/how-to-copy-content-type-in-drupal-7

Comment: sorry, question duplicated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to clone content type. I had the same issue but I handled it this way, create all of the common fields and then create one more extra field of type `list` and you can call it `Field Type`, this field is a list of content types. When you are entering content, you only need to select an item from list to distinct among content types.